# Changing bibliography format in word

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, bibliography

Is there a way to take a word document that has footnotes and turn it into a woks cited page?

Comment: Are the footnotes the works cited?

Comment: Yes... I wish to take them and then make them a page at the end as opposed to footnotes.